# Difficulty with select by attributes using list fields in for loop

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, select-by-attribute, loop, error-000358

I am trying to add fields to a table and then populate the fields with text values (Yes/No). The text values are based on whether or not a species was found in a specific block. If the species was found in a block then the field > 0 and if no species was found in a block then field = 0.

I am having issues with my select by attribute `where` clause. Specifically, I am trying the use the field name text from my `ListFields` function in the sql statement `(where_clause= field4 + " > 0")`.

I get the following error:

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Purpose is  to generate a table with presence/absence data for blocks falling outside of species ranges 

blocks = r"C:\Users\Range\Workspace\scrap\FB_Ground_MLR.shp"

# layer for make feature

blyr   = r"C:\Users\Workspace\scrap\FB_Ground_MLR.lyr"
lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features = blocks, out_layer = blyr)  

fields = arcpy.ListFields(blocks)
x = 0

for field in fields:
    field4 = field.name
    f4 = field4[0:8] + "X"
    x = x + 1
    if x >= 4:
    arcpy.AddField_management(blocks, f4, "TEXT")                  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause= field4 + " > 0")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(blocks, f4, 'Yes')
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause= field4 + " = 0")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(blocks, f4, 'No')
else:
    print(f4)
```

Comment: There's a indent error in your source.

Comment: You need to add field delimiters surrounding field4. Use tool arcpy.addfielddelimiters. For example `clause = "{0} > 3".format(arcpy.addfielddelimiters(field4)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still having issues with the where clause (where_clause= "{}" >= "0" .format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(blyr, field4))). It still gives me the invalid expression error.

Comment: Are you working with 2 featureclasses: the first a polygon fc indicating blocks and the second fc some sort of species point data? If so, I would do a spatial join, add a new text field, and populate that new field with Y or N based on `join_count` > 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer...`:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\somefolder\Default.gdb\an_riks_Intersect'
lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='templyr')

print type(lyr)
<class 'arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjects.Result'>
```

Then `lyr` will be a [Result object](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm) and cant be used in a sql Query. In my example output layer to use in query is `'templyr'`.

And when constructing the sql Query, use [AddFieldDelimiters](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) and enclose the whole Query in quotes:

```
sql = "{0} > 0".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters('templyr','somefieldname_of_number_type')
```

Example:

```
print arcpy.GetCount_management(in_rows='templyr')
sql = "{0} > 2000000000".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource='templyr', field='Shape_Area'))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view='templyr', where_clause=sql)
print sql
print arcpy.GetCount_management(in_rows='templyr')
```

Outputs:

```
294
"Shape_Area" > 2000000000
67
```

Answer (score 1):

Your where_clause needs to use SQL syntax. Using the format() function in Python is a good way to put together your where_clause if you're looping through variables. In your case, it would be:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause= "{} >= 0".format(field4))
```

More info on the format function can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/